# Excel formula/VBA to get unique values of two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

For the following data in excel, I want to retrieve the unique pairs via Formula/VBA. Can someone please suggest a solution?

```
NAME    RESULT
atest   PASS
atest   PASS
atest   PASS
atest   FAIL
atest   PASS
btest   PASS
btest   PASS
btest   PASS
```

The output should like follows.

```
NAME    RESULT
atest   PASS
atest   FAIL
btest   PASS
```

Comment: [***Have you tried anything?***](http://whathaveyoutried.com) You can start by recording a macro, using the "Remove duplicates" button and see the code

Comment: No, I would prefer Formula/VB script

Comment: Recorded macros *generate* VB code, so you can start there. Please read the link I gave you in my previous comment. Edit your question to include your attempts

Comment: @Dinesh -  VBScript is not the same as VBA, so you need to be careful and make sure you really mean what you say, otherwise poeple waste time on answers you dont realy want.

Comment: Apologies, I will modify the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub remove_duplicates()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$14").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=VBA.Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Edit the range and the `VBA.Array(1, 2)` with the number of your columns if you have more than two

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to use pivot table instead or maybe adding a third column with a simple "&" like

```
=A1 & " " & B1
```

which will give a result like "atest PASS" then you can easily put on a pivot table.

If you really want to use VBA, I can try to help on that too.